# Как убрать окно при первом запуске apk файла?

Tags: java, apk

не подскажите как убрать окно при первом запуске apk файла?
Я, разобрал apk, но не нашёл строку которая вызывает это окно!

Ссылка на окно которое вылазиет http://j-p-g.net/if/2019/09/08/0984779001567951004.jpg

Ссылка на сам apk фаил https://yadi.sk/d/UUlVCvRbwotgBg

Comment: А как искали окно?

Comment: Декодировал apk, и искал строку каторое вызывает это окно...

Comment: Вряд ли кто-то реально пойдёт по сомнительным ссылкам и что-то оттуда будет скачивать. Попробуйте выложить код прямо в вопросе, как и картинку. Тем более, что ссылки протухнут и вопрос станет полностью бессмысленным и бесполезным для сайта как для базы знаний.

Comment: в декомилированном  арк ищите строки из сообщения, по строкам, метод, откуда их вызывают и тд до победы

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл место.

Класс `android.support.v4.main.a`

Метод `a`.

Можно найти поиском в проекте по строчке `VkdWc1pXZHlZVzBnUTJoaGJtNWxiQQ==` которая при двойном прогоне через base64 даёт `Telegram Channel`.

Comment: Дальше думаю справишься)